# Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <service>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep getting this error despite adding android:exported attribute in my manifest file. No matter what I do, the code won't execute. I am trying to make a video conferencing app using firebase and jitsi SDK. I have correctly examined all possibilities of what caused this error, but I came empty-handed.

Error

> 

Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

> 

Here Is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hangout">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Hangout">
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Module:Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hangout"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.+') { transitive = true }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to note which version of Android Studio you're using. Also, did you do any searches for this issue? It's useful to note that as well with a quick summary of the results. Eg."I didn't find anything useful."

Comment: I think your issue is the very outdated jitsi-meet-sdk. Try the latest 4.1.0